# future continuous or future simple?

Tags: future-continuous

> - John won't be driving to work any more after his arrest for being drunk at the wheel.
> - John won't drive to work any more after his arrest for being drunk at the wheel.

Do these sentences mean the same? Does the first mean that is a temporary situation that will last a long time? Does the second mean that he is not allowed to drive to work anymore?

Comment: #1 sounds more like a consequence while #2 sounds like a decision, but both could be read both ways. Both sound permanent.

Answer (score -1):

As stated [here](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/future-continuous/):

> **The future continuous refers to an unfinished action or event that will be in progress at a time later than now.**

I found a person who asked the same question as you [here](http://www.really-learn-english.com/whats-the-difference-between-simple-future-tense-and-progressive-future-tense.html). He got a very good answer, from which I inspired mine.

The simple future gives you one information : **the action will occur in the future.**

The future progressive gives you the same information, ***AND*** it also tells you that the action will be **in progress**.

For example:

> "Tomorrow at nine o'clock I will be watching TV, so don't call me."

This sentence tells you that the action of watching will be IN PROGRESS at nine o'clock.

So to conclude, I will quote the person who answered the question I linked:

> *If you simply want to state that the action will happen in the future, you can use the simple future.*
>
> *If you would like to say that the action will happen, and you want to **emphasize that it will be in progress at some time**, you can use the future progressive tense.*